# Where can I find market volume data with greater resolution than 24hr periods?

Tags: charts, market-depth, volume

I have scraper that pulls data from coinmarketcap for all coins for all historic periods (down to 15min intervals) however, the only volume info available is 24hr volume. Does anyone know if it's possible to get 15m/1hr volume data (historic) from coinmarketcap? Failing that, any reasonable approach for converting the 24hr data to 1hr/15m? It would only be a rough estimate, I know. I don't know why they don't provide hourly volume data as well.

Comment: Certainly it is available - just search around.  But anything more fine than close price will cost a little in order to use the API of the service to which you subscribe.

Comment: Thanks SDsolar but I don't quite follow. The scraper I use pulls all the data that is used to produce the Graphs for each coin. I don't see any reference to 1hr volume data anywhere on coinmarketcap.com which is why I'm questioning whether any background tables contain this info.

Comment: @SDsolar: Thank you for suggesting the edit, but please make sure that what you suggest provides a _significant_ improvement.

Answer (score -1):

You could do your own price comparison.

So if you scrape every 15 minutes. Store that 15 minute price data and create your own percentage based on the history of the data you collected.

If you have the data every 15 minutes you could even do the difference in 15 minutes intervals.

Example:
Price now is $1.00.
Our database says the price 1 hour ago was $1.15
Change of -13% over the past hour.

Again, store all the 15 minute scraping price data in your database and then use that data to make the percent based on whatever time frame you want.

Comment: Thanks Marc but it's only the volume data where I need more granularity. I have 24hr volume data updated each hour but I need hourly vokume data. I was see if the data was available or alternatively whether I could estimate it from 24hr data (updated hourly). Thanks